# How to write a SQL query for the following result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-pivot

This is my current table data:

| Godown_Column | Product_Column | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Godown 1 | Product 1 | 10 |
| Godown 1 | Product 2 | 20 |
| Godown 2 | Product 3 | 30 |
| Godown 3 | Product 3 | 40 |

Here, `Godowns_Columns` has unlimited number of rows with different godowns.

How do I write a SQL query to get this result:

| Product_Col | Godown 1 | Godown 2 | Godown 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 10 |  |  |
| Product 2 | 20 |  |  |
| Product 3 |  | 30 | 40 |

Comment: Consider using pivot which transform Rows -> Columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: Search the site for "dynamic pivot"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic pivot since number of godowns is unknown.

Schema:

```
 create table mytable(Godown_Column varchar(50),    Product_Column  varchar(50), Quantity int)
 insert into mytable values('Godown 1', 'Product 1' ,10);
 insert into mytable values('Godown 1', 'Product 2' ,20);
 insert into mytable values('Godown 2', 'Product 3' ,30);
 insert into mytable values('Godown 3', 'Product 3' ,40);
```

Query:

```
 DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
 DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
 
 
 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + quotename(Godown_Column)
             FROM mytable
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,1,'')
         
 
 set @query = 'SELECT Product_Column,' + @cols  + '
              from 
              (
 select * from mytable
              ) x
             pivot 
             (
                 sum(quantity)
                 for Godown_Column in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p'
 
 execute(@query)
```

Output:

| Product_Column | Godown 1 | Godown 2 | Godown 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 10 | null | null |
| Product 2 | 20 | null | null |
| Product 3 | null | 30 | 40 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=bd9ed4f4f43fcdcee2b3d33b76c6cac3)*

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH GODOWNS(Godown_Column,     Product_Column,     Quantity) AS
(
    SELECT 'Godown 1',  'Product 1',    10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Godown 1',  'Product 2',    20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Godown 2',  'Product 3',    30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Godown 3',  'Product 3',    40
)
SELECT D.Product_Column,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Godown_Column='Godown 1' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)AS GODOWN_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Godown_Column='Godown 2' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)AS GODOWN_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Godown_Column='Godown 3' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)AS GODOWN_3
FROM GODOWNS AS D
GROUP BY D.Product_Column
```

GODOWNS is yours data example. Please replace reference to it with the reference to the actual table

Comment: Godowns are not fixed, they are unlimited, even don't know the name too, I have just mention the example there as godown 1, .... ?

Comment: So you can have Godown1....Gowndown100 ? If yes, then I guess you can try to google "dynamic pivot". As far as I remember, there is an article from ItzikBen-Gan about its implementation

Comment: But dynamic pivot example in googling also need to pass the name of columns, I didn't find the exact solution, I have followed this link https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/

Comment: Please take a look https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/dynamic-pivot-by-sql-server-instructor-jeff-jones/